# How to automatically manage domains on behalf of their owners?

Tags: dns, administration

Assume I have a list of domains that are owned by my clients. They can be registered via different domain providers. I can ask the clients to somehow configure their domains so that to confirm I can perform some operations to them.

In my system I want to be able to configure domains so that they can be linked to different IP's. For example, today I link it to `177.100.2.101` and after some time I want to change it to `157.2.2.157`. In the process of switching the IP address that is associated to a domain I don't want to have to contact clients and ask them to perform any action.

Is it possible without clients having to transfer domains ownership to me? If so, where do I find more information about it, and what's the right way to make it work?

Comment: Do you want to have control over one specific clients hostname (like `yourservice.example.com`) or you need full control over all domain records?

Comment: I need to have full control on all domain records, like `clientdomain.com`, `anotherone.net`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two (similar) ways I can see this is possible:

1. They need to create another user for you which will have access to their existing DNS provider's web console or API (with appropriate permissions).
2. You will host all their zone data on your name servers (name servers that you have control of), and they will enter your name servers as authoritative for their domain name. That way you have full control of the zone data, but they remain the owners and can easily take the control back if they wish.

Comment: Second way seems to be the most suitable to me. So, I need to have a name server which they will configure once I send IP of it to them? Should I use some paid DNS service to handle it, like https://dnsimple.com/?

Comment: I don't have experience with them so I can't recommend. I mostly use AWS lately (I like the user interface, API, and billing scheme, and I host many other services there so I enjoy the unified web console), but any well known DNS provider will probably suffice.